# Is the word "people" omitted in this passage?

Tags: ellipsis, literature

> “A basis is thus provided for explaining the unique indifference of this literature to certain cultural aims implicit in the aesthetic rendering of experience—to ideas generally, to theories of value, **to the wit of the speculative and problematical**, and to that new-fashioned sense of irony which at once expresses and modulates the conflicts in modern belief.”
>   <sub>--*[Modern Criticism](http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=qVyLzvs5qKUC&pg=PA498&dq=%22A+basis+is+thus+provided+for+explaining+the+unique+indifference%22)* by Walter Sutton, Richard Foster.</sub>

Is the word ***people*** omitted in the bolded section?

Here's my paraphrase (including ***people***):

"... to ideas generally, to valuable theories, **to the wit of the speculative and problematical *people***, and to that new type of sense of irony which both expresses and adjusts the conflicts surrounding our modern belief?"

Comment: The comma after the second to last *and* looks spurious.  It isn't shown in [another quoted version](http://cafeirreal.alicewhittenburg.com/review2a.htm)

Comment: @jwpat7 I agree. It shouldn't be there, but it's there anyway. Link updated (to make it easy to find in the original).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quoted passage says a basis is given that will allow explanation of an indifference to some cultural aims.  The items after the long dash are elements of a list of “certain cultural aims”:

> 1. ideas generally
> 2. theories of value
> 3. the wit of the speculative and problematical
> 4. that new-fashioned sense of irony which at once expresses and modulates the conflicts in modern belief

The elements of the list each stand alone; in particular, the phrase  “which at once expresses and modulates the conflicts in modern belief” modifies only  “that new-fashioned sense of irony” and does not affect other elements of the list.

Notes:

“Theories of value” does not mean valuable theories; instead, it refer to ideas about values of things or schemes.

“The wit of the speculative and problematical” is referring not to speculative and problematical people but instead to speculative and problematical situations or ideas.

The fourth item apparently asserts that conflicts in modern belief are expressed via a sense of irony.  It claims (incorrectly) that this sense of irony is a modern invention.  The meaning of  “modulate a conflict” is not clear to me but I suspect the phrase is intended to claim the existence of a higher level or a meta-level of awareness.

Answer (score 0):

This is not meant to be an answer, but I think I cannot make my points clear enough in just comments alone. Also, I found the quoted sentence quite challenging, and I consider this question as my own exercise too. If I am wrong in some aspects, please avoid down-voting and consider leaving comments instead. I really want to learn from this question.

After reading jwpat7's answer I've revised this answer. I agree with jwpat's answer and found that the answer is very useful, especially for pointing out that the items after the long dash are elements of a list of ***“certain cultural aims”***.

I found this sentence is very hard to parse, and even after I think I parsed it successfully, I am still unsure if I parsed it right. However, knowing that the items after the long dash are a list of “certain cultural aims”, here is how I think we should parse it:

> A basis is thus provided for [ explaining (the unique indifference of this literature) [ to certain cultural aims (implicit in the aesthetic rendering of experience)—(to ideas generally), (to theories of value), (to the wit of the speculative and problematical), and, [ to that (new-fashioned sense of irony) which at once (expresses and modulates) (the conflicts in modern belief) ] ] ].

In short, the sentence is about *a basis that is provided for explaining*.

It is explaining *the unique indifference (of this literature) to certain cultural aims*.

There are several cultural aims that was aimed to: *ideas generally*, *theories of value*, *the wit (of speculative and problematical)*, and *(that new-fashioned) sense of irony*.

It is this *sense of irony* that *expresses and modulates* the conflicts in modern belief.

---

As for your question: Is *the wit of the speculative and problematical* the wit of such people?

In my opinion, they can be interpreted so. <del>But I prefer to interpret them as a wit of two kinds, namely *speculative wit* and *problematical wit*. (Although I'm not quite certain what *problematical wit* means, I believe that it should mean the wit of problem posing and problem solving.)</del>

---

EDIT (2015): I've reread the question *before* reviewing my own answer. My old parsing is generally correct. (I edited the bracketing only a little.) My old opinion about "people" was omitted or not, though generally correct, was not as assertive as it should have been.

My current opinion is: Yes, it's likely omitted; but because the word *people* is not there, it appears to me that even though the writer seems to suggest so, it'd be easier for them to deny any claim that they meant so. So, whether or not they meant so should be a) more obvious in the context, or b) the omission was intentionally used as a hedge.

Comment: However, in a later sentence this author says Philip liked Henry James' "life beyond its primitive limits." So does this mean Henry James was not about experience, in spite of the points made in the point that American writers are concerned about experience in the essay.

Comment: @kih1930 I couldn't find that phrase "life beyond its primitive limits". (Reading from Google Book's image is difficult for my eyesight.) It might be easier for me if I can read the whole essay. Are you reading it from a paper book or an online e-book somewhere?

Comment: http://lareviewofbooks.org/essay/the-writer-as-reader-melville-and-his-marginalia/  This is the link.

Comment: @kih1930 First of all, thank you for a magnificent essay, though I've read up to only about one-third of it (just to the end of the quote in this question), it has already made me become interested in genuine English literature. Secondly, with my apologies, the correct quote from the essay is: *"Rahv goes on to prefer Henry James’s “expansion of life beyond its primitive needs” to Hemingway’s “bedazzlement by sheer experience,” ..."* I've never known any one of them before, nor their works, except for that Hemingway being mentioned in some movies. [con't]

Comment: [con't] As far as I can tell, *"life beyond its primitive needs"* doesn't have to be restrictively the opposite of *"bedazzlement by sheer experience"*. I believe that both, according to Rahv's opinion, require one's experience in life. It's just that Henry James's will not satisfy with "experience" alone, as the essay seems to imply. I might be wrong because this is new to me. But according to what I've just read, that is my opinion.

Comment: No problem. Same here. Now we are flooded with all kinds of pulpy novels and deluded into thinking that they are the "Jane Austens" of the 21st century or whatever by those sleek marketing blurbs. But they are a far cry from being  canonized in the pantheon of literary Gods. So the best way to spend your time reading anything is to courageously dive into an ocean of deathless literary Leviathans and fight your way through it.